# How to rebase commits to one branch while following the time order?

Tags: git

How do I rebase two branches into one so the commits are ordered by time of creation?

Example situation:

```
* cf28348 (HEAD -> master) g [2019-01-07]
* 2613a13 d [2019-01-04]
| * 887ba70 (feature) f [2019-01-06]
| * 96c6abf e [2019-01-05]
| * 909eee5 c [2019-01-03]
|/  
* ed32245 b [2019-01-02]
* 645aaf9 a [2019-01-01]
```

Desired result (hashes ommited):

```
* (HEAD -> master) g [2019-01-07]
* f [2019-01-06]
* e [2019-01-05]
* d [2019-01-04]
* c [2019-01-03]
* b [2019-01-02]
* a [2019-01-01]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to rebase and keep commits in chronological order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31492207/how-to-rebase-and-keep-commits-in-chronological-order)

Comment: @jonrsharpe The linked question is similar, but does not answer this one.

Comment: Then [edit] to clarify how.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not sure what to edit. If you look at the linked question, the answers are only describing how to modify commit dates, which is not what I need. Moreover, none of the answer is even accepted.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether or not the answers are accepted: whether or not the OP has accepted one, any other may be more useful to you. Why does creation order matter here, then? Have you tried an interactive rebase?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Interactive rebase is a solution, but I have to manually reorder the commits. I was hoping that this could be done automatically.

Comment: Well you can see the options at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase, as far as I'm aware you'd have to do something external to that for the behaviour you want. Again though it's useful to explain *why* you want that, to avoid http://xyproblem.info

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two consecutive rebase operations, but the serious downside is that the result will not end up being a child of either the `master` or the `feature` branch: it will branch off at the first place where the commits where reordered. It also means you'll have to use `push -f` to push this change, which might not make your team happy.

If you don't mind that caveat, try:

```
MERGE_BASE=`git merge-base master feature`
git rebase master
git rebase -i $MERGE_BASE
```

then you will have to manually order your commits:

```
pick 0a95943 c
pick 7e0c4a3 d
pick 57b52d2 e
pick 84a23b7 f
pick 0ad6b79 g
```

In the rebase window, you won't see the dates, so I would run this command in a parallel window to help:

```
git log --graph --decorate --author-date-order master feature
```

I saw in the comments you'd like a non-interactive solution: if you want to automate this further, you could write a parser for the output of that `git log` command with `--pretty=oneline` added to extract the commits to pick in the right order, but there does not seem to be any option to `rebase` that does this.

In fact, this log command will be much easier to parse:

```
git log --pretty=oneline  --author-date-order $BASE..feature $BASE..master
```

and here is a minimal parser for it that generates what you need to give to the interactive rebase:

```
| tac | sed 's/^/pick /'
```